# Android lock screen

Tags: android, text, locking, screen, lockscreen

Is there a way to display text on lock screen? Like the information about unread SMS messages or like that Music Player on lock screen with Play/Pause buttons.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes and no. Their is no public API to create or modify the lock screen. Whoever built the OS version on your device created your lock screen. Some of the manufacturers or carriers have added additional things to the lock screen. I've seen some that tie in to the music app, HTC sense has a somewhat customizable lock screen. So if you were willing to create your own rom and flash it to your device you could write your own lockscreen. Short of that the best you can do is write an app that the system thinks is an alternate home screen that has some kind of lock mechanism before the actual home is displayed. Then you set your device not to use a lock screen(so that it won't show both) This is not a great solution however, there are bound to be more ways to access the device if you use a "fake" lock screen like that so if security is an issue I wouldn't mess with it at all.

You might be able to find one of these "fake" lock screens on the market that suites your needs or you could create one that is exactly what you want. You could also search around on XDA for a rom that works with your device, 3rd party roms may be more likely to have the features your looking for on the lock screen.

If you end up making a pretend lock screen by using the home replacement method I strongly suggest you do not distribute something like that on the market. It is insecure and the users are unlikely to realize that there is a difference between that and a legit lock screen. Plus there is no guarantee that this method doesn't get broken at some point.

Comment: Hi Tim but i show many application in the market they provide some functionality over lock screen also see customized lock screen app in market so what do you think about it

Comment: The second part of my answer speaks about these "lock screen" that you can find on the Market. These are not actually lock screens. They are in essence a homescreen replacement that puts their own lock mechanism up before the homescreen that you are used to is displayed. They are not "real" lock screens as far as the system is concerned.

Comment: Wow!! Great answer! Thnx FoamyGuy.!